# android source build fails: undeclared identifier 'ftruncate'

Tags: android, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, android-source

I wanted to build the android source code by using this documentation:
https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html

last step was: 'make -j16'

After a while the compilation is aborted with the following error message:

```
host C++: libart <= art/runtime/catch_block_stack_visitor.cc
host C++: libart <= art/runtime/catch_finder.cc
art/compiler/elf_stripper.cc:122:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ftruncate'
  int result = ftruncate(file->Fd(), offset);
               ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart-compiler_intermediates/elf_stripper.o] Fehler 1
make: *** Warte auf noch nicht beendete Prozesse...
```

I have no idea.
Google did not help and I am really not into this topic, just wanted to do a little change to the android code (I have not changed anything yet).

My system is:

```
ubuntu 13.10
java 1.6.0_4
current android master branch
```

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you find any resolution so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this problem by adding

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

at the beginning of elf_stripper.cc

Comment: this header IS included at elf_stripper.cc